# Install ovritsdk inside a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, lxml, libxml2

right now i am trying to develop some ovirt application. The development
happens inside some virtualenv, where i am trying to install the ovirt-engine-sdk-python
package over pip. But everytime i try to install the package pip installer claims
it can't find libxml/xmlversion.h . The headerfiles are installed on my System and 
i also can find them. So my question is, does the pip install fails inside the virtualenv
because of pip cant find the headerfiles inside that virtualenv. This is the error output:

```
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:346:0:

/home/dirk/Dokumente/devel/python/bla2-0/devEnv/build/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:9:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

 #include "libxml/xmlversion.h"

                               ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Kind regards,

Dirk

Comment: Try running sudo apt-get install python-dev and then try to install your package again.

Comment: Python devel headers are allready installed so that can not be the issue :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay looks like i solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install lib32z1-dev
```

and then inside the virutalenv:

```
pip install lxml
pip install ovirt-engine-sdk-python


python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ovirtsdk
>>> from ovirtsdk.api import API
>>>
```

worked for me :)